# How to convert the svg outcome to png?

Tags: png, svg, diagrams

I am using this package to generate a sequence diagram

https://github.com/francoislaberge/diagrams

Here is a very simple sequence diagram file:

```
  Alice->Bob:Hello
```

I ran this command

```
 diagrams sequence test.sequence test.svg
```

and the `diagrams` utility generates a svg file

[image]

Then I want to convert it into png format

```
convert a.svg a.png
```

However it emits this error message:

> convert: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `,' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4430.

and it is the png file

[image]

Is there anyway I can fix this problem?

Here is some version info:

```
$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.9-16 Q16 x86_64 2020-01-12 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(3.1)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr png tiff webp xml zlib
```

and the OS is MacOS Mojave

**EDIT**:

Per @harrymc's comment, I tried to add the svg file to the question. However the image hosting service does not accept the svg file. I will paste the xml inside the svg file here directly:

```
<svg height="174" version="1.1" width="176.796875" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with RaphaÃ«l 2.1.4</desc><defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><path stroke-linecap="round" d="M5,0 0,2.5 5,5z" id="raphael-marker-block" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><marker id="raphael-marker-endblock55-obj19" markerHeight="5" markerWidth="5" orient="auto" refX="2.5" refY="2.5" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><use xlink:href="#raphael-marker-block" transform="rotate(180 2.5 2.5) scale(1,1)" stroke-width="1.0000" fill="#000000" stroke="none" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></use></marker></defs><rect x="10" y="20" width="68" height="38" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></rect><text x="20" y="39" text-anchor="start" font-family="Andale Mono, monospace" font-size="16px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: start; font-family: &quot;Andale Mono&quot;, monospace; font-size: 16px;"><tspan dy="6" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Alice</tspan></text><rect x="10" y="116" width="68" height="38" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></rect><text x="20" y="135" text-anchor="start" font-family="Andale Mono, monospace" font-size="16px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: start; font-family: &quot;Andale Mono&quot;, monospace; font-size: 16px;"><tspan dy="6" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Alice</tspan></text><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M44,58L44,116" stroke-width="2" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><rect x="98" y="20" width="48.796875" height="38" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></rect><text x="107.9921875" y="39" text-anchor="start" font-family="Andale Mono, monospace" font-size="16px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: start; font-family: &quot;Andale Mono&quot;, monospace; font-size: 16px;"><tspan dy="6" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Bob</tspan></text><rect x="98" y="116" width="48.796875" height="38" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></rect><text x="107.9921875" y="135" text-anchor="start" font-family="Andale Mono, monospace" font-size="16px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: start; font-family: &quot;Andale Mono&quot;, monospace; font-size: 16px;"><tspan dy="6" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Bob</tspan></text><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M122.3984375,58L122.3984375,116" stroke-width="2" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path><text x="59.19921875" y="83" text-anchor="start" font-family="Andale Mono, monospace" font-size="16px" stroke="none" fill="#000000" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-anchor: start; font-family: &quot;Andale Mono&quot;, monospace; font-size: 16px;"><tspan dy="6" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Hello</tspan></text><path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M44,96C44,96,100.13640903495252,96,117.4049332986342,96" stroke-width="2" marker-end="url(#raphael-marker-endblock55-obj19)" stroke-dasharray="none" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></path></svg>
```

Comment: You could give InkScape a try. I can't give you an exact command, but I know for a fact that it can export SVG to PNG from the GUI, so there's probably a corresponsing CLI command too.

Comment: You could post the SVG file for examination.

Comment: @harrymc I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SVG file is behaving strangely. On Windows, I observed the following:

- All browsers can display it : Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Pale Moon
- Some paint programs will not accept it : Paint.NET, PhotoShop 6
- One paint program does accept it : Zoner Photo Studio
- On the Web, at least one free online conversion website can handle it :
  [SVG to PNG](https://svgtopng.com/).

It seems that the `diagrams` package produces an SVG image with slight errors,
so the display program needs to be programmed in a permissive way.
Programs that require a fully correct file will fail.

I suggest to use whatever tool that can work with these non-standard files,
the above website for example.

You could also post a bug report for this issue on Github for the `diagrams` project.